# Name ''total'' is not defined

Tags: python-3.6

What should I differently? The Result is line 12 print(total) NameError: name 'total' is not defined

```
def gross_pay (hours,rate):

   info =()
   info = getUserInfo()
   rate = float(input('How much do you make an hour?:'))
   hours = int(input('How many hours did you work?:'))
   total = rate * hours
   taxes = total * 0.05
   total = total - taxes

print(total)
```

Comment: Just indent your `print(total)`

Comment: There's more wrong than that.  Calling the function is needed.  The parameters to the function aren't used, but input in the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

`total` is a local variable.  It doesn't exist outside the function.  Also you need to call the function, where you can return total.  `getUserInfo()` is not present and `info` is unused.  Asking for the input parameters inside the function is incorrect as well.  Technically, pay after taxes is net pay, not gross:

```
def net_pay(hours,rate):
   total = rate * hours
   taxes = total * 0.05
   return total - taxes

rate = float(input('How much do you make an hour? '))
hours = int(input('How many hours did you work? '))
print(net_pay(hours,rate))
```

Output:

```
How much do you make an hour? 10.50
How many hours did you work? 40
399.0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def gross_pay (hours,rate):

   info =()
   # getUserInfo() should also be defined on your code:
   info = getUserInfo()
   rate = float(input('How much do you make an hour?:'))
   hours = int(input('How many hours did you work?:'))
   total = rate * hours
   taxes = total * 0.05
   total = total - taxes

   print(total)    

#calling the declarated (defined) function:
hours=0
rate=0
gross_pay()
```

I'm assuming you're passing the parameters **hours** and **rate** by reference because you're gonna need the values later, otherwise they're not necesary, since you're asking for input inside the **gross_pay** function